# if statement that sees if there is any value in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

6 and would like to know how to make a if statement that checks if theres any type of value in a variable.

```
number = random

if number (has a value in it)
    print ("Your variable has a number in it")
elif number (doesn't have a value in it)
    print ("Please input a number in the variable")
else:
    print ("unknown error, restarting")
```

Thanks for any help i get with this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'has a value'? It is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your variable must be a string in this case:

```
var1 = '2333'

if '4' in var1: 
    print('found it') 
else:
    newVariable = var1 + '4'
    print(newVariable)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you understood this. It is better to *not* post an answer until the OP clarifies what exactly they are after.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a variable contains a number:

```
var = input("Enter a number")

try:
    int(var)
    print("Value is a number")
except ValueError:
    print("Value is a not a number")
```

Alternatively, to check if the variable has been set:

```
var = input("Enter a value")

try:
    var
    print("Variable has a value")
except NameError:
    print("Variable has no value")
```